# Can't find how to count friendship connections between Montreal and Toronto (SQL)

Tags: sql

Please I can't find the SQL request allowing me to count the number of connections of friends between 2 cities.I want to know how many connections exist between montreal and toronto for example.

Here is an example of concerned tables from my database (sorry I couldn't make things well aligned):

**`Cities`** table

```
C_ID | Name
C1 | Montreal
C2 | Toronto
C3 | New York
```

**`User`** table

```
U_ID | C_ID | Name
1 | C1 | Jack
2 | C1 | Hilary
3 | C2 | Stefan
4 | C3 | Luis
```

**`Friends`** table

```
F_ID | U_ID1 | U_ID2
1 | 1 | 2
2 | 1 | 3
3 | 2 | 4
4 | 1 | 4
5 | 4 | 3
6 | 3 | 2
```

that would be really nice if someone can help me with that !!! Thanks

Comment: What is the expected results you are looking for for these sample data?

Comment: Aside: you don't need the `F_ID` column. Just create a composite key on `U_ID1` and `U_ID2` and a check constraint `U_ID > U_ID2`...

Comment: actually I'm still a beginner at sql ! i know i have to use "Count" function to count generated records (if im not mistaken) but i'm not able to write whole the request. in this example there are 2 relations between montreal and toronto (record 2, record 6 in friends table) so i need to obtain the result 2 ! thank you for your help guys

Comment: That shouldn't be too difficult. Google a bit (e.g. for SQL and JOINS) and try something yourself. If you get stuck people will help you here. Just explain what you've tried first and post the SQL you've tried.

Comment: Please also tell us which DBMS you are using (Oracle, Postgres, ...). The answer *might* be DBMS dependent.

Comment: kdzia سْكِرْتِي... رَوحِي !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like that:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friends 
JOIN user AS u1 ON (u1_id = u1.id) 
JOIN user AS u2 ON (u2_id = u2.id)
JOIN city AS c1 ON (u1.city_id = c1.id)
JOIN city AS c2 ON (u2.city_id = c2.id)

WHERE (c1.name = 'Montreal' AND c2.name = 'Toronto')
OR    (c2.name = 'Montreal' AND c1.name = 'Toronto')
```

Here is an SQLFiddle-Demo for your problem: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94097/8)

Comment: Thank you very much Andi that really makes sens what you said and i totally understood it ! But when i put it in Access there is a message appearing like: "Syntax Error in FROM clause" and it's not accepted. Yet, i don't see where the problem is that's weird ! Thank you again for your help

Comment: I don't know the Access syntax. Probably you have to change the 'JOIN' to 'INNER JOIN'

Comment: Well i tried it on sqlserver and that worked very well ! I still have the choice to avoid access. thank you very much andi !!!